# How modify code - Pop up window, additional closing options

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, popup, clicking

I have animated pop-up box that can be closed only when clicked on "X" button in left top corner. Do you know how to change it, so it can be closed by:

1. Clicking `ESC` button
2. Mouse clicking in background around pop-up
3. Any other suggestions?

**Code**

```
function openOffersDialog3() {
  $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
    $('#boxpopup_3').css('display','block');
    $('#boxpopup_3').animate({'left':'30%'},1000);
  });
}


function closeOffersDialog(prospectElementID) {
  $(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','absolute');
      $('#' + prospectElementID).animate({'left':'30%'}, 0, function() {
        $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','fixed');
        $('#' + prospectElementID).css('left','100%');
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
      });
    });
  });   
}
```

Comment: Thx for edit, something've gone wrong while writing it by me ;x

Answer (score 0):

pass ESC button id to `closeOffersDialog()` function, I think it will work